# User registration and authentication using hashed passwords

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a game project (with Unity) that shall handle user credentials and other data. The game connects send requests to a php script and this script send requests to the database. After spending some days learning about sql injections and password handling, I came up with this approach. I am obviously still very naive with all this, but I would like to know if it is good or not. The first one is the script for creating a new user, and the second one is for login.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "whatever";
$password = "whatever";
$dbname = "whatever";

try {

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);


    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    $salt = bin2hex(random_bytes(strlen($_POST["providedpass"])));
    $hashpsw = hash('sha256', $_POST["providedpass"].$salt);

    $name = $_POST["usrnm"];


    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt, level) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

    if ($stmt->execute(array($name,$hashpsw, $salt, 1))) {

        echo "USER CREATED";
    }


    $db = null;

} catch (PDOException $e){

    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

-

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "whatever";
$password = "whatever";
$dbname = "whatever";

try {


    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);



    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");



    $providedname= $_POST["usrnm"];

    $stmt->execute(array($providedname));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

            echo "FOUND USER";

            $hashpsw = hash('sha256', $_POST["providedpass"].$row->salt);

            if($hashpsw == $row->password) {

                        echo "CORRECT CREDENTIALS";

            }





    }

    $db = null;

} catch (PDOException $e){

    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it is not safe. You can refer to the [following article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-php-renewed_2/index.html) thet explains why you shouldn't use SHA-family hashing and required to use password_hash() instead. Beside other things, it means that salt field should be removed, and password field should be varchar(255).

To soften the pill, I've got the [reference code to check the hashed passsword](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash).

There is one more issue which is connected to security: wherever an error occurs, **you are echoing it right in the hands of a potential hacker**, revealing a lot of sensitive information about your software, database structure, etc. You should never ever be doing things like  `echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();`! For more info refer to my article on the basics of [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)

Everything else is rather good, save for *peculiar code formatting* and unnecessary WHILE statement. When you expect just a single row, there is no need to run a while loop. Just fetch your row right away.

Also, it does no good to duplicate the database connection code. Store it in a file and just include wherever needed.

So the refactored version would be like

db.php:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "whatever";
$password = "whatever";
$dbname = "whatever";
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
try {
     $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

register.php

```
require 'db.php';
$hashpsw = password_hash($_POST["providedpass"],);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, level) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST["usrnm"], $hashpsw, 1));
echo "USER CREATED";
```

auth.php:

```
require 'db.php';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['usrnm']]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();

if ($user && password_verify($_POST['providedpass'], $user['password']))
{
    echo "FOUND USER";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll follow your advices.

Comment: Would it be secure to store the username and the hashed password in the session variables?